# How does this code work to determine the positions of nearest neighbours in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor

Could someone help explain how this code works?

```
right = @(i) mod(i, n) + 1; 
up = @(i) mod(i, n) + 1; 
left = @(i) n + 1 - right(n - i + 1); 
down = @(i) n + 1 - up(n - i + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`x=@(i) f(i)` creates an 'anonymous function', called `x`, that is equivalent to the following:

```
function out=x(i)
out=f(i); 
end
```

It just happens that anonymous functions are often much more convenient in Matlab than creating another file -- here the little snippets `right(i)` and friends return the values that I presume make sense in the context you're working in.

Comment: `<% Function, calculating interaction of a given atom at position (i, j) with its four neighbours
hloc = @(s, i, j) H(s(i, j), s(right(i), j)) + ...
               H(s(i, j), s(i, up(j))) + ...
               H(s(i, j), s(left(i), j)) + ...
               H(s(i, j), s(i, down(j)));>`